# What are some methods to fix a broken Unity *session* (no re-login)

Tags: unity, dconf

The top bar with the applets and the main system menu is missing but, what's worse, `dconf` and `gsettings` have no effect even though dconf-service is running.

What methods would you try that don't apply only on reboot or relogin?

If you need to break your session in order to test together with me, just use a combination of `unity --reset-icons` and `killall -9 compiz`. It kind of works all the time.

Comment: Whenever the desktop breaks I simply reboot. But It think I've had to do a Ctrl+Alt+F1 before and use `startx`. Might work in your experiments.

Answer (score 1):

## **The Secret Command to Reset Ubuntu Desktop to Default Settings:**

```
dconf reset -f /
```

---

**Reset Unity:**

```
unity --reset
```

**Reset Unity Launcher icons:**

```
unity --reset-icons
```

**Reset Compiz in Ubuntu 11.04 or newer:**

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
unity --reset
```

You can also try:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
```

## **Restart Ubuntu’s Unity Without Logging Out :**

**Option 1:**

```
unity --replace
```

**Option 2:**

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

**Reinstall unity :**

```
sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity
```

Edit :

**Some other fixes :**

```
export DISPLAY=:0   
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

And :

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
```

**Reinstall ubuntu desktop as last resort :**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: This fixes some problems and deserved my vote. I still can't make the "panel" show up and clicks raise windows other than the ones they were intended for.

Comment: Check my edit. To reinstall unity.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last command involves a relogin.

Comment: True, I let it as edit incase some other people got the same issue. I don't think you can fix ALL problems without a relog tho. You could try "sudo service lightdm restart "

Comment: In case some other people get the same issue, they have two other questions on askubuntu. This question is unique because of the no relogin constraint. Anyway, a warning for who is interested in this question: the `sudo service lightdm restart` in the comment above also violates the explicit requirement in the title. It implies *relogin*

Comment: "--reinstall install unity " doesnt require a relog btw.

Comment: I know, that's why I mentioned only the `shutdown` and the `lightdm restart`. I even safely used `--purge remove compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 libunity-core-6.0-9 unity unity-schemas unity-services`. Is there any way to safely restart `dconf-service`?

Comment: Maybe " unity --replace " or " dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ " ? Check option 1 and option 2 in my answer.